# Trust my work domain on a Dev Domain without a domain level password

Tags: domain, active-directory

I setup a virtual machine to host a dev version of TFS (to test plugins on).

Getting a computer on my work domain requires large amounts of red tape and paperwork that I would rather not do.

I created my own domain the the VM and I would like to trust all users from my work domain on that VM Domain.  But when I tried to setup the trust I needed a password from my work domain (which I don't have).

Am I trying to do something nefarious?  I just want to be able to authenticate to my Test TFS (VM) Server as me (my login on my work domain).

Is there a way to do that with out having to have a domain level password for my work domain?

(My VM is a Windows Server 2008 R2 server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is something nefarious. Trusts between domains in Active Directory do require not just domain level credentials, but domain-admin credentials. It sounds backwards, but even one-way trusts need foundations in both domains.

Comment: Dang.  So there is no way to use my domain login to access the VM TFS?

Comment: I don't know TFS, so there may be something in that specific application that'll do it. But based purely on AD, you're out of luck.